A new graph product and its properties
We define a sequence of graphs $\{B_0, B_1, \dots B_k \dots \}$ as follows:
Consider a seed graph $B$ with a vertex set $V(B) = \{v_1, v_2, \dots v_n\}$ and an edge set $E(B)$. The sequence is constructed iteratively as follows:

Define the graph $B_0 = (V(B_0), E(B_0))$ where $V(B_0) = \{v_{0,1}, v_{0,2}, \dots v_{0,n}\}$, and $E(B_0) = \{(v_{0,i}, v_{0,j}): (v_i, v_j) \in E(B)\}$.
For $k = 1, 2 \dots$ define the graph $B_k = (V(B_k), E(B_k))$, such that
\begin{equation}
                    \begin{split}
                        & V(B_k) = V(B_{k - 1}) \cup \{v_{k,1}, v_{k,2}, \dots v_{k,n}\}; ~\text{and}\\
                        & E(B_k) = E(B_{k - 1}) \cup \{(v_{k,i}, v_{k,j}): \text{if}~ (v_i, v_j) \in E(B)\} \cup \{(v_{0,i}, v_{k,i}): i = 1, 2, \dots n\}.
                    \end{split} 
                \end{equation}
If the seed graph is $P_2$ we present the first few members of this sequence in the below figure:


Now I have the following questions:

Is this graph sequence discused in the literature of graph theory?
If it is already discussed, what is its standard name?
If it is already discussed please provide some references.

Thank you.
